# Laravel controller / store

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel, i am trying to store a tweet to database and i need to insert user id, but this gives me an error

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Tweet;

class TweetController extends Controller
{

   public function store(Request $request){

return Tweet::create([ 'tweet' => request('tweet'), 'user_id' => Auth::id()]);

    }
}
```

error i recive:

> App\Http\Controllers\Auth' not found in file
>   /Applications/AMPPS/www/Twitter/Twitter/app/Http/Controllers/TweetController.php

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are missing the import, that's why it tries to find it in the `Controller` location, so put

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

// or 

use Auth; // you must have the Auth alias in the config/app.php array
```

as an import, or use the helper function `auth()->id()` instead.

So instead of mass-assigning the user, you can do the following, in your `User` model add this:

```
public function tweets()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Tweet::class);
}
```

Then in your controller just do this:

```
auth()->user()->tweets()->create([ 'tweet' => request('tweet') ]);
```

Comment: so in the `Tweet` model, you are missing `user_id` in the `$fillable` array.

Comment: After that i recived General error: 1364 Field &#039;user_id&#039; doesn&#039;t have a default value (SQL: insert into `tweets` (`tweet`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (my first tweet, 2019-06-11 06:18:36, 2019-06-11 06:18:36))

Comment: I commented before you removed your comment the first time, but I edited my answer as well, take a look.

Comment: @StefanAvramovic did my answer helped? Isn't it acceptable?

Comment: i use laravel with vue, and tried to use api/routes with csrf_tokens, my solution was using web/routes and the problem was fixed. -- "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;" helpd me..  Thanx!

Comment: no my friend, you probably voted up, accepted is when you mark the check-mark on the answer, it will light up in green.

Answer (score 1):

You can use auth() helper to get user id:

```
auth()->user()->id
```

Comment: Tis gives an error  Trying to get property of non-object in file /Applications/AMPPS/www/Twitter/Twitter/app/Http/Controllers/TweetController.php

Comment: Then you are not logged in, so you should check for logged in user before fetching the ID. like this: `$id = auth()->check() ? auth()->user()->id : null;`